# issue displaying associated record in show action rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason I'm having an issue displaying an associated record on my account show page.

I have the following models:

`account.rb` has the association of: `belongs_to :plan`
`plan.rb` has the association of: `has_many :accounts`

```
# accounts_controller.rb
def show
  @account = Account.find(params[:id])
  @account.plan = Plan.find_by(params[:plan_id])
end
```

When I try to display the Plan name on the account page, it only displays the first plan name (even through i have multiple plans and the account has the plan_id properly set.

ie Account 1 has a plan_id of 2 but displays the info for plan 1 where as Account 2 has the plan_id of 1 and that shows the proper plan...

Not sure where I'm veering off course here any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `Plan.find_by(params[:plan_id])` here, find_by needs an attribute which to look for, which I guess would be the account_id, right?, try `Plan.find_by(account_id: params[:id])`, or I'm not sure is it  `Plan.find(params[:plan_id])`? Anyways you define the `@account.plan` but you need to persist that data, be sure on applying a `save` after all that.

Comment: put that in an answer and ill award best. thanks!

Comment: Did it work, which part for being more specific?

Comment: This was the final solution: ```@account.plan = Plan.find(params[:id])```

Comment: See the answer, I've added other approaches, do you need just the first plan for that specific account, or all of them (as is a belongs_to-has_many relationship)?

Comment: just the plan for that specific account..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord/FinderMethods#find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) find and returns the first record matching the conditions, but for that you need to pass the attribute which you're looking for and the value assigned, in your case you're passing just the value.

If you're planning on getting the plan for that specific account then `Plan.find(id)` would be enough.